# Chamar um metódo da classe do próprio fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Boa tarde, tenho um fragment que possui o seguinte XML

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/salvar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradiente_azul_semconor"
    android:text="Salvar"
    android:textColor="@color/cinza"
    android:onClick="salvarUsuario"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout" />
```

Mas eu não consigo selecionar no onclick a função salvarUsuario que está na classe desse fragmente, apenas as funções que estão na activity pai.

Seria essa a função:

```
  public void salvarUsuario(View view){

        EditText nomeEt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(nome);
        EditText emailEt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(email);
        EditText npEt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(np);
        Spinner tipoFuncSp = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(tipoFunc);
        Button salvarBt = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(salvar);

        usuario.setNome(nomeEt.getText().toString());
        usuario.setEmail(emailEt.getText().toString());
        usuario.setTipoFunc(tipoFuncSp.toString());
        usuario.setNp(npEt.getText().toString());

        db_funcao bd = new db_funcao(getContext());
        bd.inserir(usuario);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Usuário inserido com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Como eu faço para chamar um função que está na própria class do fragment e não na activity principal.

obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remova essa linha do XML:

```
android:onClick="salvarUsuario"
```

2) Dentro do OnCreateView() do Fragment coloque esse código antes do return:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nome_do_xml, container, false);

    ...

    Button salvarBt = rootView.findViewById(R.id.salvar);
    salvarBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            salvarUsuario();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

3) A sua função salvarUsuario pode ser alterada para (remover parâmetros):

```
public void salvarUsuario(){
    ...
}
```